# Update javascript object properties inside of a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game in javascript and i'm currently trying to get my x's and o's appear when I click on the spaces (divs). I have my system so that my ticTacToe() object "game" can update through it's object prototype.

The problem is since I use a for loop to attach click event handlers to all the divs with the "space" class, I can't access the properties of the "game" object at that scope. If I use "this" i'd be referring to the div itself. I've tried making a prototype function and a constructor function to update the "currentPlayer", "board" and "turn" properties of the game object but I can't manage to get the browser to recognize that the properties are in the game object.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="gameBoard">
    <h1 id="msg">Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
    <div id="tl" class="space"></div>
    <div id="tm" class="space"></div>
    <div id="tr" class="space"></div>
    <div id="ml" class="space"></div>
    <div id="mm" class="space"></div>
    <div id="mr" class="space"></div>
    <div id="bl" class="space"></div>
    <div id="bm" class="space"></div>
    <div id="br" class="space"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function ticTacToe() {
  this.board = [[0,0,0]
               [0,0,0]
               [0,0,0]];
  this.turn = 0;
  this.currentPlayer = 1;
}

ticTacToe.prototype = {
  status: function(){
    console.log("The number of turns played is " + this.turn +
    " and it is player " + this.currentPlayer + "'s turn.");
  },
  attachClicks: function(){
    var spaces = document.getElementsByClassName("space"),
        player = this.currentPlayer;
    for(var i = 0; i<spaces.length; i++){
      spaces[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(player == 1){
          this.style.backgroundImage = "url('x.png')";
          //Update ticTacToe's turn, player, and board
        }
        else {
          this.style.backgroundImage = "url('o.png')";
          //Update ticTacToe's turn, player, and board
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

var game = new ticTacToe();

window.onload = function(){
  game.attachClicks();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind another variable to `this`:

```
  attachClicks: function(){
    var game = this;
    var spaces = document.getElementsByClassName("space")
    for(var i = 0; i<spaces.length; i++){
      spaces[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(player == 1){
          this.style.backgroundImage = "url('x.png')";
          //Update ticTacToe's turn, player, and board
        }
        else {
          this.style.backgroundImage = "url('o.png')";
          //Update ticTacToe's turn, player, and board
        }
      })
    }
```

Then you can refer to `game.board` and `game.currentPlayer` in the event listener function to access the current `tictactoe` object.

Comment: Have to tested this? I don't think it will work. I think According to his code you this will refer to function, not the object.

Comment: @GeekAb When you do `game.attachClicks()`, `this` refers to the value of `game`, which is the object.

Comment: `this` never refers to the function in Javascript.